# In AOSP10, we have found that onNewIntent() was called before the "FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT" flag was set

Tags: android, android-activity, frameworks, onnewintent

In AOSP10, we have found that onNewIntent() was called before the "FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT" flag was set.
This phenomenon is already reported and it is addressed only in the AOSP7 platform.

We like to understand below queries:

1. Why it is applied only in AOSP7 platform?
2. Why the fix is not ported to AOSP8 through AOSP10 platform.?

Please answer anyone of you for the above queries.

Reference Link :
[https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/frameworks/base/+/f73d0853953198945b905695c93e562209a861c5]

We are did not get the any reference.